# How to replace Unicode character in a string?

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-10.1-berlin

I need to replace a literal [UNICODE character](http://www.codetable.net/hex/25b6) with a "normal" character in a string:

```
HTMLString := StringReplace(HTMLString, '??', '->', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

But I cannot enter this Unicode character in the Delphi code editor because of the Delphi code editor not being able to display this Unicode character.

I can clearly see that the above Unicode character is inside the string because when I send the string with CodeSite I can see it in the CodeSite Live Viewer:

```
CodeSite.Send('HTMLString', HTMLString);
```

This is a screenshot from the CodeSite Live Viewer:

[image]

So how can I replace this Unicode character in the string?

Delphi: 10.1 Berlin

Comment: The Delphi IDE supports Unicode since version 2009. You can enter Unicode text in the source code if you change the file encoding to UTF-8. To do this, choose "File format | UTF8" from the editor context menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi IDE support `Unicode` since V2009, just right click in the code editor go to `File Format` then select `UTF8`, and here is a simple sample to replace the unicode char:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
Var
 S: Char;
 Str: string;
begin
  S:= chr($25b6); // Or S:= chr(9654);
  Str:= S + 'Hi there' + S;
  Caption:= Str + ' ---> ' + StringReplace(Str, S, '', [rfReplaceAll]);
end;
```

> Among the many new features found in Delphi 2009 is the imbuing of Unicode throughout the product. The default string in Delphi is now a Unicode-based string. Since Delphi is largely built with Delphi, the IDE, the compiler, the RTL, and the VCL all are fully Unicode-enabled.

To read all the article: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38437

Comment: Although having changed the file format to `UTF-8` in the Delphi Source Code Editor, the above Unicode character was still not displayed: https://i.imgur.com/6h9MYIo.png . - The `chr($25b6)` trick finally did work. Is there a general rule to derive the `chr ordinal` from the UNICODE character? Is there a "calculator" where I can enter the literal Unicode character and get the chr value as an output?

Comment: @user1580348 Hmmm weird did you try to save the unit and re-open it?

Comment: In the link you just provide in your question, there is a hex code like `&#x25b6` just replace the `&#x` with `$`

Comment: Sure. Here is the file-format screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/9VdXPkC.png . - But is there a **general rule**?

Comment: General rule for what? the ordinale number is `9654` you can do also `S:= Chr(9654);`, If you pass you unicode character to `Ord()` function you will get `9654`

Comment: You wrote: "pass you unicode character to Ord()". But how can I do that if I cannot enter the literal Unicode character in the Delphi editor as I have demonstrated with a screenshot?

Comment: But here is an Unicode character search site: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=▶&preview=entity

Comment: @user1580348 "*Although having changed the file format to `UTF-8` in the Delphi Source Code Editor, the above Unicode character was still not displayed*" - it is not enough to save the source file in UTF-8. You also have to make sure the editor is set to use a font that supports the Unicode characters you are interested in.

Comment: So why is the Delphi 10.1 Berlin source code editor not able to display this Unicode character ▶ after having changed the file format to `UTF-8`? (See screenshot above).

Comment: @RemyLebeau The font is "Courier New". I have just tested it in a word processor: This font can display the character ▶

Comment: @RemyLebeau No, this is not the case cause I have courier new too and I can type the unicode character even the file format is ANSI. (Delphi 10 Seattle)

Comment: @RemyLebeau So why is it not working with my Delphi 10.1 Berlin?

Comment: Strange: Pasting from the clipboard does not work: I get the usual empty square character. But when entering `Alt + 25b6` (as Sami suggested) I get this character ♠ instead of ▶ !!! Isn't this weird? So how can I get the character ▶ with the Alt method?

Comment: @user1580348 "Courier New" DOES NOT have `▶` (U+25B6 BLACK RIGHT-POINTING TRIANGLE). Verified with Windows Character Map. When I paste U+25B6 into *any* text editor using "Courier New" active, the character DOES NOT display correctly (in fact, Office Word insists on changing the font to "MS Mincho" when pasting). However, "Courier New" DOES have `►` (U+25BA BLACK RIGHT-POINTING POINTER) instead.  Similar but different characters

Comment: @user1580348 `ALT + 25b6` is not a valid ALT keycode.  The ALT keycode for `♠` is `ALT + 6`. The correct ALT keycode for `►` (U+25BA, U+25B6) is `ALT + 16`.